# Is there a way for ruby's net/http to support openssl configurations placed in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf?

Tags: ruby, openssl, net-http

I haven't been able to confirm, but is it true that net/http will NOT honor the options/values set in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf? I have been trying to make some TLS changes to support a downstream legacy TLS connection, and it works using the openssl s_client but my rails app keeps throwing the OpenSSL errors.

If true, is there a workaround or way to get the config file honored by the ruby/rails app? I haven't been able to find one.

I've tried exposing ssl_options to net/http and then making changes that way and that works but I'd rather make the change in the openssl.cnf file and have it be honored by net/http instead.

Comment: What web server is your rails app using?  If it's using net/http I'm almost afraid to ask.  You're not using webrick in production are you?